# Why does percpu offset is subtracted while allocating dynamic percpu memory using pcpu_alloc() , what is logic behind this?

Tags: memory-management, kernel

Why does percpu offset is subtracted while allocating dynamic percpu memory using pcpu_alloc,  what is logic behind this?

Answer (score 2):

while calculating the actual address of the percpu variable, we can add the percpu offset. and this process should be same for all cpu's including the primary cpu.